# Flatten Dataframe After One Hot Encode

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am fairly new to Python.  I have a dataframe with 2 columns

df =

```
brokerid, insurer
broker1, insurer1
broker1, insurer2 
broker1, insurer3
broker1, insurer4
broker2, insurer1
broker2, insurer3
broker2, insurer2
```

I have one hot encoded the df such that it looks like

```
        insurer1, insurer2, insurer3, insurer4
Broker1   1          0          0         0
Broker1   0          1          0         0
Broker1   0          0          1         0
Broker1   0          0          0         1
Broker2   1          0          0         0
Broker2   0          0          1         0
Broker2   0          1          0         0
```

I want it to look like this

```
        insurer1, insurer2, insurer3, insurer4
Broker1   1          1          1         1
Broker2   1          1          1         0
```

I'm sure it must be easy (one liner even).  But how please?

I have tried numerous things

Answer (score 0):

Apply [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) on the initial df:

```
pd.crosstab(columns=df.insurer, index=df.brokerid)
```

---

```
insurer   insurer1  insurer2  insurer3  insurer4
brokerid                                        
broker1          1         1         1         1
broker2          1         1         1         0
```